# Three js raycaster WITHOUT camera

Tags: three.js, raycasting

I seem to find only examples to use the raycaster with the camera, but none that just have a raycaster from Point A to Point B.

I have a working raycaster, it retrieves my Helpers, Lines etc. but it seems it does not recognize my sphere.

My first thought was my points are off, so i decided to create a line from my pointA to my pointB with a direction like so:

```
var pointA = new Vector3( 50, 0, 0 );
var direction = new Vector3( 0, 1, 0 );
direction.normalize();
var distance = 100;

var pointB = new Vector3();
pointB.addVectors ( pointA, direction.multiplyScalar( distance ) );

var geometry = new Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push( pointA );
geometry.vertices.push( pointB );
var material = new LineBasicMaterial( { color : 0xff0000 } );
```

var line = new Line( geometry, material );

This will show a line from my point (50 0 0) to (50 100 0) right trough my sphere which is at point (50, 50, 0) so my pointA and direction values are correct.

Next i add a raycaster: 
To avoid conflicts with any side effects i recreated my points here:

```
var raycaster = new Raycaster(new Vector3( 50, 0, 0 ), new Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ).normalize()); 
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(target);
console.log(intersects);
```

Seems pretty straight forward to me, i also tried to use raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children) but it gives Lines, helpers etc. but not my sphere.

What am i doing wrong? I am surely missing something here.

IMG of the line and the sphere:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is explained in the following github issue:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/11449

The problem is that the ray emitted from `THREE.Raycaster` does not directly hit a face but its vertex which results in no intersection.

There are several workarounds to solve this issue e.g. slightly shift the geometry or the ray. For your case:

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( new THREE.Vector3( 50, 0, 0 ), new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0.01 ).normalize() );
```

However, a better solution is to fix the engine and make the test more robust.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/kzwmoug2/3/

`three.js R106`

Comment: This is what I thought was happening, but when I applied an arbitrary rotation to the sphere (and updated the `matrixWorld`), it didn't seem to help. Maybe my arbitrary rotation wasn't so arbitrary. :)

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer, good to know my points where okay and the issue is this obscure:). For me this fixed it:

        sphere.geometry.rotateY( 0.00002 );
        sphere.updateMatrixWorld();